# Importing data from CSV file error: A query with the name ... already exists

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import data from a .csv file and then get the sum of last column.

The CSV file contents are:

```
Name,Age,City,Salary
Rick,25,Dallas,1800
Nick,28,Austin,2500
Jack,30,NYC,3500
Rose,26,Dallas,2400
```

The macro throws the following error.
[image: Macro Error]

The code looks like this.

```
Sub EmpMacro1()
'
' EmpMacro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Emp_Datta", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\Irfan.Shaikh\Desktop\Emp_Datta.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=4, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Name"", type text}, {""Age"", Int64.T" & _
        "ype}, {""City"", type text}, {""Salary"", Int64.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Emp_Datta;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Emp_Datta]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Emp_Datta"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("C7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
    Range("D7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Emp_Datta[Salary])"
    Range("D8").Select
End Sub
```

I have two questions.

1. When I stop recording the macro and delete the imported data. There is an alert to confirm deleting the query. What is the impact of Yes and No?
2. I looked into the web for the error but did not find a solution. Is it related to me deleting the query when I delete the imported data?

Comment: If you delete the query when deleting the cell data then in principle above macro shall work. Otherwise, if the query already exists and csv data structure is constant then you can choose to refresh it without running macro.

Comment: Even if I delete the query and then rerun the macro. I am getting the error which i posted in my OP. The error means to me that there is a query which is conflicting and not working.

Comment: If you are deleting the query by deleting the Range (and answering "Yes" to the question), it seems you are only changing it into a connection-only query and not really deleting it.  You need to actually delete the query, either with VBA code or in the `Queries and Connections` window, to really delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deleting the query by deleting the Range (and answering "Yes" to the question), it seems you are only changing it into a connection-only query and not really deleting it. You need to actually delete the query, either with VBA code or in the Queries and Connections window, to really delete it.

Another problem with your query is that you will be creating multiple `ListObjects` with the same `DisplayName`.  This will also cause a runtime error.

However, if the tables are on separate worksheets, as is the case with your query, they can have the same `Name` and Excel will adjust the `DisplayName` by appending a `_n` where n is a number, so as to prevent duplicate naming.

(You still cannot have tables with the same `Name` on the same worksheet).

So I would try:

```
Const sName As String = "Emp_Datta"

On Error GoTo delQuery
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=sName, Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\Irfan.Shaikh\Desktop\Emp_Datta.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=4, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Name"", type text}, {""Age"", Int64.T" & _
        "ype}, {""City"", type text}, {""Salary"", Int64.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
On Error GoTo 0

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Emp_Datta;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Emp_Datta]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True

        '---------------------
        .ListObject.Name = sName
        '---------------------

        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("C7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
    Range("D7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Emp_Datta[Salary])"
    Range("D8").Select
Exit Sub
delQuery:
    Dim v
    For Each v In ActiveWorkbook.Queries
        If v.Name = sName Then _
            v.Delete
            Resume
    Next v
MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
Stop

End Sub
```

And, unless there is some reason to use `ActiveWorkbook`, I'd suggest changing those references to `ThisWorkbook`.

Also note that if you **Refresh** the query, you will overwrite the data table on the activesheet; whereas if you execute your macro, you will be creating a new table on a new worksheet.

Comment: Thank you that helps. I deleted the query from the query window. Now it makes sense why the error was showing up.